# Must I flag every comment as "too chatty"?

Tags: discussion, flags

When an entire OT conversation is held in comments, I usually flag the start of the conversation as "too chatty" and assume the moderator will take the time to review the entire comment thread. But if [the moderator doesn't do that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23291865/check-if-string-exceeds-limited-characters-then-show/23291930#23291930) it seems spammy *of me* for me to flag each comment as chatty individually. I'm uncomfortable doing so many flags in a row. What is the right course of action when flagging multiple comments for the same thing?

Comment: Why constraint comments at all? IMHO any comment is ok unless it can be considered spam or offensive.

Comment: @Ivan That is perhaps a good meta question on its own. I have an answer in mind, but I will save it.

Comment: "Too chatty" is in the eye of the beholder. I often find a great deal of relevant information in the comments; regardless of whether or not they stick to the topic.

Comment: Incidentally, I do get tired of having humanity edited out of my comments. I have an irreverent, vernacular style of writing that often sub-references (for example, Sir Terry Pratchett is a favorite reference of mine). These tend to get nuked by mods. I have to assume that a humor-ectomy is part of the elevation to modhood.

Comment: @MAGSHARE To say that there are useful comments does not contradict the argument that there are also comments that are distracting, of transient use, or "inside" (as in "inside joke") so that most readers cannot benefit from them. I'm probably guilty of a few inside jokes myself, but I don't object to having such comments removed if others think it doesn't really contribute to the question or answer. It's a sort of organic content curation.

Comment: @kojiro Thanks for the response. Well, again, that depends. I have found that using vernacular, and adding a light touch often makes stuff more readable. Life's too damn short for "just the data." I used to love the Isaac Asimov books, which were "science for dumbasses," because he was so casual in his writing style. I'm no Asimov (NSS), but I think that it's important to reward folks for reading the tripe I write. God knows, it's painful enough, reading others' stuff.

Comment: Why not just leave it alone--someone will get help, learning and/or enlightment out of it and it's not hurting anyone.  Every comment will have some people that won't benifit, so should we just eliminate the comment system altogether?  Keep the moderation for stuff that is truly problematic.

Comment: @BillK how is someone going to get learning and/or enlightenment out of a series of comments like "Hey, how you doing?", "Just fine, what's new with you?", "Did you see the game last night?"… meanwhile, I'm trying to point out a relevant thing in the question or answer and my comment is getting drowned out.

Comment: Sorry, I stand corrected.  Never seen comments like that.  Guess the mod system is working better than I had thought.  I thought you were referring to inside jokes and off-topic comments, but not personal communications.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You should flag the entire post. Here are the flagging guidelines for this (https://stackoverflow.com/help/flagging)

> If you see a post where many comments should be deleted, especially if there's an ongoing discussion, there’s no need to flag each comment. Flag the post for moderator attention, and use the “other” reason explain what's going on.

Answer (score 24):

You can use a custom flag on the post containing the comments to explain to the moderators that the rest of the comments need scrubbing and not just the one that you would have otherwise flagged as too chatty.

I hear work is being done to improve the workflow for moderators which should make this less *necessary* in the future. But context always helps, and we always appreciate when users include more details in their flags for us to work with.

Comment: nvm I was thinking either the post or the comment could be custom-flagged, but then I remembered custom comment flags don't stick around when the comment is deleted solely by flags.

Comment: I think Bill's answer to [Could we have some consensus on how to flag bunches of obsolete comments?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/207967/213111) still applies correct?

Comment: Yes pretty much.