# Can the mods agree on how we should mass-flag comments?

Tags: support, flags, comments, comment-flags

There are two possible ways to mass-flag obsolete (or otherwise deletion-worthy) comments on a post:

- Raise an "Other" flag on the post noting that most/all of its comments are obsolete
- Flag every single comment individually, waiting for the 5-second timeout between each one

The mods have a long history of giving contradictory advice on which of these two approaches is better (and I have, uh, [some history of voicing my irritation about it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322702/what-is-the-correct-procedure-for-handling-large-amounts-of-trashy-comments-on-a/322739#comment342813_322739)). To cite a few different sources throughout history:

- The Help Center [says](https://stackoverflow.com/help/flagging) that

  > If you see a post where many comments should be deleted, especially if there's an ongoing discussion, there’s no need to flag each comment. Flag the post for moderator attention, and use the “other” reason explain what's going on.
- In 2013, Shog9 [says](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/203206/200582) that we should flag posts, and that flagging individual comments instead is "very rude". (Post now deleted, but the relevant section is quoted at [Flagging multiple comments versus flagging the whole post for moderator attention](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/203211/200582))
- Again in 2013, Shog9 [clarifies](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/203215/200582) that flagging individual comments is fine if the reason a comment should be deleted is obvious from the comment itself (e.g. for "thanks" or "#$@&(*#$&" comments), but that in cases where context is needed to verify which comments should be deleted, we should use a post flag instead
- In 2014, BoltClock [advocates](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252458/1709587) for flagging the post
- In 2014, bluefeet [says](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254854/1709587) that flagging posts is preferable because it's easier and reduces the risk that a moderator acting without context will delete a bad comment but leave behind a (now nonsensical) reply to it
- In 2015, Martijn Pieters [suggests](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285238/1709587) flagging the post
- In May 2016, meagar [asks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322702/what-is-the-correct-procedure-for-handling-large-amounts-of-trashy-comments-on-a?cb=1#comment342532_322739) for individual comment flags instead of post flags
- Meanwhile, Boltclock now [also expresses](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322702/what-is-the-correct-procedure-for-handling-large-amounts-of-trashy-comments-on-a?cb=1#comment342861_322739) a preference for flagging individual comments but [acknowledges](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322702/what-is-the-correct-procedure-for-handling-large-amounts-of-trashy-comments-on-a/322739#comment342740_322739) that the rate limit makes it annoying for users to flag that way

This contradictory advice has left me unsure of which approach the mods would, on the whole, prefer me to take. But they've seemed willing to clean up comments whichever way I chose to flag them, so I've just carried on flagging whichever way was most convenient for me and not worried too much.

But today, after flagging a post with many garbage comments on it, I got a flag declined with this sentence as part of the decline reason:

> For cleaning up individual comments or answers, please flag them individually.

I'd guess this is from one of our three new moderators, since in ~400 post flags (the *majority* of which were asking for mass comment removal) I've never before had this reason given for declining a flag.

This is daft! I'm not sure if anything has changed behind the scenes - lots of what we've heard from moderators hints that in the last year or two they've received better tooling for bulk-handling of comment flags, though I don't know the details. But even if it has, this situation is farciful. The mods have told us contradictory things, the Help Center and rate limit have been designed to push us towards post-flagging instead of comment-flagging, and now we have a moderator who (going against the advice in the help center) has declined a post-flag and asked for many comment flags as an alternative. What are we to make of this, exactly?

Can the moderators please talk to each other, reach an agreement on how we should be mass-flagging comments, and set forth a policy that they can all live with? I don't care *what* the policy is; I just want to be given clear, non-contradictory instructions!

Comment: I wish all meta posts had this much research. For what its worth I usually just flag one comment with "other" and as specific of an explanation as possible and have not had any declined, but it would be nice to hear some consensus from the moderation team since there is clearly some confusion.

Comment: The comments might only be part of the reason for the declined flag. Your flag stated: "Dubious merge from … (what would've been wrong with mere duplicate closure?!) seems to have brought a whole bunch of garbage comments with it that need cleaning up." and the moderator declined it with "The merge made a lot of sense, since both questions contained good answers. For cleaning up individual comments or answers, please flag them individually."

Comment: I'll ping them, but what they may have been trying to say in the comment part of that decline reason is that in this case, "garbage comments" brought across by a merge might need to be picked out of the rest individually. It could help us to identify which ones don't belong. For the record, I don't care what kind of flag we get, as long as it's made clear to me which comments I should be removing.

Comment: @BradLarson I realise this, but I don't think it changes much. I probably shouldn't've stuck a complaint about the merge into the flag reason without a clear actionable attached, but the one actionable that *was* in there (clean up a whole bunch of garbage comments) got declined, with the reason quoted. The other details seem irrelevant.

Comment: And while they're at it, can they help BoltClock make up his mind?

Comment: They probably can't. This is after all, a website in the internet.

Comment: So, no clear answer on the last paragraph, which would be great to have. When flagging individual posts, I know I can delete any comments of mine as "context" is not needed. However, do I leave such context when flagging the post with "other" - does it cause more work, or ease the task, for the Moderator if I leave my posts. I'd like to know, and I don't.

Answer (score 19):

I was the one handling that flag. Let me say this in general first:

- When raising a custom flag, please be as direct as possible with what your concern is to avoid miscommunication.
- When something needs more discussion (e.g. was this merge warranted?), post on meta where a discussion can be had; flags are the wrong place to invite discussion.
- It is indeed cumbersome to flag a lot of individual comments, so yes, flagging a single comment or the post with a "some comments need deletion" is still fine.
- If you flag a comment directly, that comment shows up for moderators directly and can be dealt with in a single click. Raising a custom flag always requires more in-detail intervention and raises the risk of misunderstandings, or of mis-judgement. So again, custom flags should be very clear about what you need a moderator to do.

It's a tradeoff for you, the flagger: individual comment flagging is more clicks but clearer, mass-flagging is fewer clicks but requires more diligence to be clear to moderators.

---

Specifically to this case, the merge target in question is here: [Migration from GCM to FCM needed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37311188)

Your flag read:

> Dubious merge from stackoverflow.com/questions/37452463/fcm-vs-gcm-why-we-need-to-migrate-from-gcm-to-fcm (what would've been wrong with mere duplicate closure?!) seems to have brought a whole bunch of garbage comments with it that need cleaning up.

My *full* decline reason read:

> Declined: The merge made a lot of sense, since both questions contained good answers. For cleaning up individual comments or answers, please flag them individually.

Now, there are only a limited amount of characters in both the flag and the decline reason text fields, you should stick to raising one issue at a time. There was no way to appropriately respond to all your raised points within the short flag decline reason. For this reason, please focus on one thing when raising a flag, and preferably something that a moderator can constructively act on.

If the flag had merely read *"some garbage comments need cleaning up"*, I'd likely have responded very differently to this flag. But since the brunt of the flag seemed to question the merge as such, that's not how it went.

I will say that I could have taken a closer look at the post in question and determined which comments need deletion, yes. Which I did now (for the record: 4 out of 8 warranted removal). In my defence, I was somewhat short on time at that moment and, again, the flag was somewhat ambiguous about what it was trying to express exactly.

Comment: *"please focus on one thing when raising a flag"* - we don't have the ability to do this unless we want to leave other issues untouched. The flag UI only lets us raise one flag at a time, so we have to raise all actionable issues. That said, the complaint about the merge would've been better on Meta. The biggest problem with it is that you've moved across a huge multi-part answer that answered distinct questions step by step onto a question where those questions *weren't asked*, which is confusing and makes it look (correctly!) like the answer has been copied from another post.

Comment: *"the brunt of the flag seemed to question the merge"* - not my intent and still not how it reads to me rereading it now, but noted. Leaving the parenthetical out would likely have made the flag easier to handle.

Comment: *"4 out of 8 warranted removal"* - when I flagged I was expecting all 8 to be nuked; of the remaining 4, the first 3 are, together, just another question posted in the comments (complete with a link to it in the third one), and the fourth is just a (poor, incomplete) answer posted as a comment. None of them provide any value.

Comment: @MarkAmery Again, if you want to discuss the details of a specific merge, please post a meta post to do so. Discussing this even here in the comments hardly allows enough space. FWIW, another user flagged both questions suggesting a merge, which seemed very reasonable to me, since both were dealing with the same canonical topic and both had great answers. — Once you properly remove this discussion from your flag, there was no reason to raise more than one issue at a time.

Comment: @MarkAmery Only 4 comments were clearly too-chatty, the others contain actual content which may or may not be useful. Unless you can point to specific reasons, I won't arbitrarily decide to clean out such comments.

Comment: Very well: I have raised a post flag explaining in detail why the 3-comment chain at the start of the comment thread should be deleted, and will flag the fourth comment individually.

Comment: I will post a separate Meta post about the merge (although I'm not entirely sure to what end; my only goal in complaining of the merge by flag or in mentioning my issues with it here was to feed back to you that it seemed wrong to me, and I don't know whether further discussion will yield anything useful - we shall see!) Of course, all of this leaves my primary question here about what mass-comment-flagging strategy is preferred (which is unrelated to this merge) unanswered.

Comment: Alright, those flags made a lot more sense and are handled now. Thanks. As I said above: mass-flagging on the post is fine, as long as *it's clear* what you're flagging. And as I'm also trying to point out: individually flagged comments are much clearer and easier to deal with for moderators. It's a tradeoff for you, the flagger: individual comment flagging is more clicks but clearer, mass-flagging is fewer clicks but requires more diligence to be clear to moderators.

Comment: I have posted a separate Meta question about the merge at http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/338937/1709587

Comment: @deceze consider moving your last comment into the answer and re-ordering the post to be general guidance first and particular case later.