# Report a single comment or multiple comments

Tags: support, users, offensive

If I saw a user that had a bad attitude to the others, and even insulted others on comments, for example,

> 1. *Why does it work? You should just delete your answer I guess.*
> 2. *Please delete your answer. I don't see how you can not understand my answer at all.*

I can't talk more about who the user is, and even the post. But I just saw these two examples happened in a certain post under a different answer. Did I need to report every single comment or should I just need to report any of them?

Comment: [Can the mods agree on how we should mass-flag comments?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338911) and [Flagging multiple comments versus flagging the whole post for moderator attention](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203211)