# deleting/flagging no longer needed comments?

Tags: discussion, comments, comment-flags, no-longer-needed

Following situation:

- I post a comment to ask for clarification or to inform OP about an issue with their question
- OP replies
- I write an answer that also covers what has been discussed in the comments (or someone else writes an answer)
- The comments are now no longer needed

If you need an example: [C++ thread safe class, not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61826948/4117728)

Should I:

- delete my own comments? That would render OPs replies without context, so should I also..
- flag OPs replies as no longer needed?
- or perhaps flag both my own and OPs comments as no longer needed so they can be deleted in one go?
- or maybe just leave it be?

Comment: Deleting your own comments and flagging the others (or maybe even custom flag the whole post and explain it, if there are several comments) is the least work for the mods.

Comment: @JeanneDark yes, least work for the mods is what I had in mind. Usually I dont do anything in such case and only flag when I think the comment should not be there in the first place. The question I linked isnt a good example, I doubt anybody would bother to clean up the "mess" there, just didnt have a better one at hand

Comment: Delete your own, then comment to the OP suggesting they clean up theirs.  If they do, delete your last comment.  Net zero work for the mods.  If they don't,  then flag for a Mod cleanup

Comment: Related https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338911/can-the-mods-agree-on-how-we-should-mass-flag-comments?rq=1 has guidance that I read as : if each individual comment is clearly no longer useful you can flag on-by one, otherwise flag "other" with clear instruction like "delete comments above this one (all incorporated into post)"

Comment: Wait.. "I write an answer that also covers what has been discussed in the comments". If the outcome of that is clarification, then the comments should not be removed until the clarification is incorporated into the Question. How else will a new potential answerer know?